# How to use multiple shader states?

Tags: c++, directx-11

For example, if I want to use `ID3D11RasterizerState` with CullMode set to `D3D11_CULL_BACK`, and then I want to change it to `D3D11_CULL_FRONT` during runtime, what is the best approach? I was creating one state for each option and setting the right one during runtime, but this is very troublesome, as I need to set a lot of different shader states for each combination. Is retrieving the description from the shader on runtime( e.g. `ID3D11DepthStencilState::GetDesc()`) and changing it on the fly a good option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you create a rasterizer state for each combination of states you want to use. Setting the active state is a pretty cheap operation--it's creating the state object that's expensive.

> Note in DirectX 12 you have to put *all* states into each Pipeline State Object so that means every possible permutation of states, shaders, and render target format/configuration will result in the need for a new PSO.

Comment: Ok thanks for your clarification, it's actually sad I'll need to create a bunch of different states, but it's what I have.